# Calculating a maximal function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{2r} [\arctan(x+r)-\arctan(x-r)]$$

I would like to evaluate the sup and give to $g$ a explicitly expression. I don't know if it is possible, at least, the way I am trying seems to go nowhere. Any help is appreciated.

PS: $g(x)$ is the [maximal function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_function) associated to $f$, i.e., $g(x)=Mf(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give $g$ explicitly when $|x|\le 1/\sqrt{3}$: namely, $g(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ in this range. Outside of this range, $g$ is a solution of some transcendental equation that mixes fourth-degree polynomial with arctangent function; this is not something that leads to explicit formulas.  You can say that asymptotically, $g(x) \sim C/x$ where $$C  = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+y^2}\,dy = \frac{\pi}2$$

---

*Proof of $g(x)=f(x)$ for $|x|\le 1/\sqrt3$.*

Suppose $x$ is such that $g(x)>f(x)$. Then the supremum in the definition of $g(x)$ is attained by some $r^*>0$. It follows that the function  $$r\mapsto r g(x) - \frac12\int_{x-r}^{x-r} f(x)\,dx $$
is always nonpositive and is zero at $r=r^*$. Hence, its derivative vanishes at $r=r^*$, which gives
$$g(x) = \frac{f(x+r^*)+f(x-r^*)}2 \tag1$$
But, 
$$f(x) - \frac{f(x+r)+f(x-r)}2  = \frac{r^2(1-3x^2+r^2)}{(1+(x+r)^2)(1+(x-r)^2)(1+x^2)  } >0$$
which contradicts $g(x)>f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting answer. Do you know if $g$ is differentiable for $|x|\ge 1/\sqrt{3}$?